# The best way to add Unix Shell variables to CURL GET request

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, curl

Let’s say I use `curl –X GET` command with the following link:

```
“$WEBSITE_URL/ACTION_NAME/ACTION1;id=$ID?Command=TEST&id1=$ID1&id2=$ID2&id3=$ID3”
```

As you can see, there are some $variables in this string. Obviously, just adding them to the string without letting Bash know where these variables start and end won’t work.

So I tried to use all kinds of tags that I found (i.e. ‘”$Variable”’, ${Variable}, etc.) to separate variables and make this string look and act more like a normal request, but none of them worked. There were some related topics here, they were helpful, but information I got still didn’t make it work – probably because my case is a bit different from basic examples and I’m missing something here. 
Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure about that `;id=$ID` _before_ the query part (`?...`)?

Comment: Explain exactly what the problem is i.e. what should happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Why do you want to use `-X GET` (as opposed to letting `curl` forget the GET request properly)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be escaping special characters properly; specifically `;`, `&` and `?`

Also, it may be a function of this website, but your double quotes aren't the quotes you're looking for: `“` isn't the same as `"`

I'd use:

`# curl "${WEBSITE_URL}/${ACTION_NAME}/${ACTION1}\;id=${ID}\?Command=TEST\&id1=${ID1}\&id2=${ID2}\&id3=${ID3}"`

Answer (score 0):

`bash` uses all characters after `$` which are valid in a variable name to determine the name i.e. the first illegal char limits the name string.

In case of doubt `${Variable}` should be used. You already mention that so your problem must be something different.

Comment: Strictly speaking `$` introduces _parameter_ expansion, variables being one type of parameters. For instance, `3`, and `#` are not valid variable names but `$3` and `$#` are valid parameter expansions. Also note that `$12` is `${1}2` (in `bash`/`ksh`/`yash`/`bourne`, but not `zsh`/`ash`).

Answer (score -1):

Create the string as a variable and pass that variable to curl.

> ```
> string="${WEBSITE_URL}/ACTION_NAME/ACTION1;id=${ID}?Command=TEST&id1=${ID1}&id2=${ID2}&id3=${ID3}"
> echo $string #this should get the right string to be passed to curl
> curl -X GET $string
> ```

Comment: That `;` needs to be quoted or otherwise it will be considered as a variable separator. Using a variable won't really help here especially if you forget to quote it.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment. I'll modify the answer adding the missing quotes.